# Given matrix $B$, find all possible matrices $A$ satisfying $ A(A-2B) = -(A-2B)A $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $A, B \in \Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$ such that $A(A-2B) = -(A-2B)A$. Given $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 & -1 \\ 2 & -4 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $$ find all possible matrices $A$ satisfying the equation above.

---

I hope there is some way faster than compute directly...

Comment: I know this equation can be transformed to $A^2 = AB+BA$, but I can not go further from this equation.

Comment: Notice that $A=2B$ works.

Comment: And I know and I can prove that the equation implies $det(AB-BA)=0$

Comment: @preferred_anon Yes, that is one type of A, thanks, and can you provide more hints?

Comment: Can you check if $A$ and $B$ commute?

Comment: Observe that you equation is equivalent to $(A-B)^2=B^2$, therefore if you can solve for $C$ in $C^2=B^2$ then you are done.

Comment: @P.Quinton It's an awesome observation! But...is there a faster way to solve $C^2 = B^2$

Comment: @林國陽 You can solve that with diagonalization.  $B$ is diagonalizable, and $B^2$ will have eigenvalues $1$ with multiplicity $2$ and $6^2$ with multiplicity $1$.  So $C$ would have eigenvalues $\pm 1$, $\pm 1$, and $\pm 6$.

Comment: @Aaron I think I can go further, let me think. Thanks for you all.

Comment: @Aaron I think if I can find out all matix C s.t. $ C^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\   
         0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 &0  & 36
 \end{pmatrix} $.  Then done. I wonder that there may exist C which is not diagoanl matrix

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia sorry, I may not think AB = BA

Comment: @林國陽 That is a reasonable worry, but by looking at JNF (or more simply the minimal polynomial) one can show that if $C^2$ is diagonalizable and invertible, then so is C. Invertibility is very important here, though.

Comment: @Aaron thank you

Comment: @林國陽 please note I said diagonalizable, not diagonal. Any reflection, for example, squares to the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint of @P.Quinton, we can rewrite the problem as $(A-B)^2=B^2$, and that reduces the problem to finding all $C$ such that $C^2=B^2$.  The difficulty here is that $B$ has a repeated eigenvalue, which means that finding all the square roots of $B^2$ is not quite straight forward.  After all, any reflection will square to the identity, and so on that eigenspace we can take something that restricts to a reflection.

We first note that $B$ is diagonalizable, with $B=PDP^{-1}$, with $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,6)$.

Because of this, $B^2$ will satisfy the polynomial $f(x)=(x-1)(x-6^2)$, and hence so will $C$.  But then $C$ will satisfy the polynomial $f(x^2)=(x^2-1)(x^2-6^2)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-6)(x+6)$ which has no repeated roots, so $C$ is also diagonalizable.  If $v$ is an eigenvector of $C$, then it is also an eigenvector of $C^2=B^2$, The problem is that when we square $C$, things that weren't eigenvectors for $C$ can become eigenvectors for $C^2$, for example if $Cu=u$ and $Cv=-v$, then $C^2(u+v)=u+v$, but $C(u+v)=u-v\neq \lambda(u+v)$.  But if we pick any two vectors that span $\ker(C^2-I)$, then we can pick them to be eigenvectors in $C$.  If they both have eigenvalue $1$ or both have eigenvalue $-1$, then the matrix we get for $C$ will not depend on our choice because $C$ restricted to their span will be $\pm I$.  If they have different signs, then the choices matter.

For the sake of computation, it is easier to find square roots of $D^2$ and then conjugate to turn those into square roots of $B^2$.  If we follow the proceedure above, then we will get block diagonal matrices, $\operatorname{diag}(M,\pm 6)$ where the first block is $2\times 2$ and the last block is $1\times 1$.  The first block, $M$ is a matrix satisfying $M^2=I_2$ (the $2\times 2$ identity matrix), which is either $\pm I$ or a matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, which can be found easily by specifying a trace of $0$ and a determinant of $-1$.  In particular, if you set the first column of $M$, those two conditions will uniquely determine the second column.

Putting everything together, $C$ is of the form $PNP^{-1}$ where $P$ was the matrix used in the diagonalization of $B$ and

$$N=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0 \\ 
\frac{1-a^2}{b} & -a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \pm 6 
\end{pmatrix}$$

(except when $b=0$, in which case $a=\pm 1$ and the $(2,1)$ entry can be anything), or where $N$ is one of the other forms already discussed.

Comment: Do you think something of the following flavor is true ? If we solve $A^2=U J U^\ast$ with $J$ a (positive definite not necessarily symmetric) Jordan block matrix and $U$ unitary. Then essentially all "square roots" are $U J' U^\ast$ such that the Jordan blocks correspond if we square them, but can be positive of negative. I guess this would mean that the number of square root of a matrix is essentially $2^k$ where $k$ is the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to non zero eigen values.

Comment: @P.Quinton I reread what you wrote, and something like that is kind of true.  If we are trying to solve $X^2=A$, we can split our vector space into its generalized eigenspaces for $A$ and then solve the problem on each eigenspace.  While there will in general be infinitely many solutions for each eigenspace if it is multiple dimensional (and one generalized eigenspace can split into two when square rooting), there is at least some structure we can take advantage of.  But even identifying the potential JNF of square roots still leaves the more difficult task of actually finding all of them.

Comment: @Aaron Super thanks for your answer, and now I have tried to understand your answer. I think that let N be a direct sum of 2x2 and 1x1 matrices is smart, this save our time for computing. And now, the only one thing I can't sure is why N must be a direct sum of 2x2 and 1x1 matrix？

Comment: @林國陽 our vector space splits into eigenspaces for $N$, and any eigenvectors of N is automatically an eigenvectors for $N^2=D^2$.

Comment: @Aaron Can you explain: "But if we pick any two vectors that span $Ker(C^2−I)$, then we can pick them to be eigenvectors in C."？

Comment: @林國陽 If you pick $u, v$ and you define $Cu=\pm u$, $Cv=\pm v$, then $u$ and $v$ are both eigenvectors of $C^2$ with eigenvalue $1$.  The only obstruction to constructing a square root in this manner is if the two vectors weren't linearly independent, hence the condition that they span the eigenspace.

Comment: I think I am able to write down the right answer. Thank you very much.